# Unable to run docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am inside organization infrastructure. And using Windows 7 machine. I have Hyper-V enabled and Docker toolbox installed. Due to firewall blocking while Docker, host machine cannot access, Oracle VM box machine, So, I have adopted an work around of port-forwarding and this helps me to pull image and start container as usual.

But whenever, I am trying to use `docker-compose up`, the command fails with error, `docker-compose: not found`

**Version Details**

```
Boot2Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build HEAD : 404ee40 - Thu Mar 22 17:12:23 UTC 2018
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
```

**Step-1:**

```
λ ssh docker@127.0.0.1 -p 51712
docker@127.0.0.1's password:
```

**Step-2: Navigating to folder where docker-compose.yml file is there and making it up.**

```
docker@default:~$ cd /c/Users/pranaygupta/Docker/Images/artillery-tests/
docker@default:/c/Users/pranaygupta/Docker/Images/artillery-tests$ ls
artillery/          docker-compose.yml  grafana/
docker@default:/c/Users/pranaygupta/Docker/Images/artillery-tests$ docker-compose up
-sh: docker-compose: not found
```

Any help to solve this issue, will be great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by opening the internal proxy and setting to dedicated internal repository for installing docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose is not found, install it with `pip install docker-compose`

Comment: do you know when we do port forwarding like above, and start any container with -p 3000:3000, how to open that url in browser?

Comment: localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000